# Can we explicitly start a system service in Android?

Tags: android, android-service

In my android project we are facing an issue -

'When an Edit Text box is focused and appropriate action is taken', the keyboard does not appear up.

This issue occurs like once in 50 times.

We analyzed the issue and found that -

Input Method Service is not running when this issue occurs. (We checked logs) Input Methods Service is used to get instance of Input Manager, which is further used for other things.

I have to do more analysis
So I have two questions -

1. Could it be a problem related to memory management ? I mean is it possible that the system is killing the service when certain memory situation occurs ?
2. If the service is killed and not running, can we explicitly start this service through our code in application?

Please Help.

Comment: I doubt that such a system service would crash.Because if it does then there's a bug on AOSP.Such an critical issue should not be a `un-fixed` bug!

Comment: Then what could be the reason for service not running?

Comment: Are you sure that its happening because of the service not running.It also happens due to some flag on the `EditText`

Comment: Yes its because of the service. can we start the service on our own?

Comment: The service is bit modified, though.

Comment: `Layout.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);` <-- have you tried this?

Comment: yes. that is already there.